# loading external content and appending it

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, append

I am trying to load some text from an external file, append this and then pass it to a div container but cannot get the append to work

```
$.get('gallery-lightbox.html', function (data) {
    var lb_content = data;
    $(lb_content).append('<p>some text</p>');    
    $('#lightbox').load(lb_content);
    positionLightboxImage();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$.get('gallery-lightbox.html', function (data) {
     var lb_content = data+'<p>some text</p>';    
       $('#lightbox').html(lb_content);
       positionLightboxImage();
});
```

**OR**

```
 $.get('gallery-lightbox.html', function (data) {
           $('#lightbox').append(data).append('<p>some text</p>');
           positionLightboxImage();
    });
```

And make sure your `gallery-lightbox.html` file doesn't have `<html>` or `<body>` tag etc. it should only have the `<div>` or an element that you can actually put inside your `#lightbox`